# How do you pass a JSON object through a snowflake stored proc then loop through the key values

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I'm trying to pass a JSON object containing fully qualified tables into a stored procedure so I can loop through it and put the key values into a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_db.proc_schema.json_test(
    tables VARIANT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    key_value_pairs VARIANT;
    keys_array ARRAY;
    key_value OBJECT;
    key STRING;
    database_name VARCHAR;
    table_for_tables VARCHAR;
    sql_command VARCHAR;
BEGIN

## parsing through the JSON object but commented out since it will parse in the FOR loop anyway
-- sql_command := (SELECT PARSE_JSON(:tables));

## create a table to put the extracted key values into
    table_for_tables := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE proc_db.proc_schema.JSON_OBJECTS (DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :table_for_tables;

## loop through the JSON object and put the extracted database_name into the DATABASE_NAME column in the table
    FOR key_value IN (SELECT PARSE_JSON(:tables))
    DO

## split the key value in the JSON from the first full stop to get database_name
        database_name := SPLIT_PART(:key_value, '.', 1);

## insert into the table
        sql_command := 'INSERT INTO proc_db.proc_schema.JSON_KEY_VALUES (DATABASE_NAME) VALUES('||:database_name||');';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_command;
        
  END FOR;
      
      RETURN 'Success!';
END;
$$;
```

This is the call block:

```
call proc_db.proc_schema.json_test(
      PARSE_JSON('{
        "tables": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_TABLE","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2"]
      }')
);
```

The result I want is to have a table with DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, OBJECT_NAME in a table with each object_type underneath the correct column, e.g DB_PROD_1, DB_PROD, DB_DEV under DATABASE_NAME etc.

And I've gotten an error 'Executing NULL statement is not permitted.'. I think it may have something to do with the SPLIT_PART part because when I set the database_name variable outside of the FOR loop and tried to return it,

```
    database_name := SPLIT_PART(:key_value, '.', 1);
    RETURN :database_name;
```

it says 'Invalid argument types for function 'SPLIT_PART': (OBJECT, VARCHAR(1), NUMBER(1,0))'. Not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update code for

1. above script misses lot's of snowscripting syntaxes.
2. Table created and insert are not matching.

Below is script to start with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE json_test(
    tables VARIANT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    key_value_pairs VARIANT;
    keys_array ARRAY;
    key_value OBJECT;
    key STRING;
    database_name VARCHAR;
    table_for_tables VARCHAR;
    sql_command VARCHAR;
BEGIN


-- parsing through the JSON object but commented out since it will parse in the FOR loop anyway
-- sql_command := (SELECT PARSE_JSON(:tables));

--# create a table to put the extracted key values into
    table_for_tables := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE JSON_OBJECTS (DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :table_for_tables;


    let query := '
    select value::varchar key from table (flatten(PARSE_JSON('''||tables||'''):tables::array)
      )';
    let rs resultset := (execute immediate :query);
    
    let   c1 CURSOR FOR rs;

-- loop through the JSON object and put the extracted database_name into the DATABASE_NAME column in the table
    FOR key_value IN  c1
    DO

    key := key_value.key;
-- split the key value in the JSON from the first full stop to get database_name
          select SPLIT_PART(:key, '.', 1) into database_name;
    
-- insert into the table
        sql_command := 'INSERT INTO JSON_OBJECTS (DATABASE_NAME) VALUES('''||:database_name||''');';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_command;
        
  END FOR;
      
      RETURN 'Success!';
END;
$$;

call json_test(PARSE_JSON('{
            "tables": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_TABLE","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2"]
          }'));


select * from JSON_OBJECTS;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much this worked thank god! I was wondering, how would I add schema_name and object_name into the table. I added the columns into the creation of the table and I try to insert into the table like so
```
          select SPLIT_PART(:key, '.', 2) into schema_name; -- etc

        sql_command := 'INSERT INTO JSON_OBJECTS (DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE) VALUES('''||:database_name||''', '''||:schema_name||''','''||:object_name||''','''||:object_type||''');';
```
but it keeps saying Invalid identifier SCHEMA_NAME, not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I also want to extract the key from the JSON so basically "tables" and set it to a variable to add it to the table under "object_type" but not sure how!

Comment: Cross Check below 1) Did you declared SCHEMA_NAME?
2) Did you updated create or replace temp table to add new columns.
I see these two issue only for 1st comment

Comment: Regarding addition of object_type, if you are sure there will be only one key, you use below query to get the key and use it below
``` select OBJECT_KEYS(
        PARSE_JSON('{
        "tables": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_TABLE","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2"]
      }')
      )[0]::varchar; ```


If more, then you need to get output of above keys and loop through them.

Comment: Sorry my longer answer was deleted. so I have an updated call block
call json_test(PARSE_JSON('{
            "tables": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_TABLE","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2"],
            "views": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_VIEW","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW"]
          }'));
and I'm trying to loop through it to extract the OBJECT names e.g. "tables", "views" and I want them to be entered into the tables under OBJECT_TYPE along with their corresponding column of database,schema, object.

Comment: How would you get the output of all keys for tables, views etc cause currently it's only giving me values for tables?

Comment: Create resultset for query like ``` select value::varchar key from table (flatten(OBJECT_KEYS( 
PARSE_JSON('{ "tables": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_TABLE","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_2"], "views": ["DB_PROD_1.DB_PROD_SCHEMA.DB_PROD_VIEW","DB_PROD.MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW", "DB_DEV.MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW"] }')
))); ``` and iterate over every row and pass that value dynamically to above answer. So you need one more loop on output of above query and that will nest original answer